# Unable to boot or do internet recovery

Tags: macos, mac, bootcamp, ssd, recovery

I have with me a Mac Mini Late 2012 model (Core i5, 6630M). It was running like a champ despite its age but recently while watching Netflix, the screen had a glitch and hung. I force restarted it.

After the reboot, it fails to load the OS and would stall at a blank white screen after the loading bar completes. Had tried resetting the PRAM, ran diagnostics and only had this error - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203648 (which seemed like a false positive)

I took out the SSD and was able to boot it up with another mac. I wiped it clean anyway and re-insert in back to the mac mini. I tried doing USB boot and internet recovery but the issue still persist. The recovery modes, just like the OS never boots and stalls at the white screen.

From the looks of it, it seems like the motherboard is having some issues loading up the OS, given that I tried multiple boot options (recovery, normal os) that were working previously.

Has anyone encountered similar issues or have some clue to what may be happening?

Comment: Is it just a grey screen no matter what you do?

Comment: I've had this problem. Never solved it

Comment: @sam It boots to a blank white screen and doesn't go away... Ah.. Tough..

Comment: I'm afraid that your computer may be fried. If you manage to find a solution though, please share

Comment: See if it can get through the [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/HT201257) before giving up. Hold D at power on..

Comment: hey @Tetsujin, I ran the AHT earlier and the only error it returned was the issue listed in question - which seems like a false positive.

Comment: @sam sadly.. but hopefully not.. will definitely share if it starts working again.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Did you run the full tests, not just the quick ones?

Comment: yeah, i ran the extended version and that was the only error it returned. unless they cut off the test on the first error they detect

Comment: i managed to boot into my os again.. but it seems that my dedicated gfx is fried... @sam i found this video useful to get the mac to boot again.. but its not the same anymore.. - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9esGch26G_A

Comment: Did you by change set a firmware password right before it stopped working?

Comment: I don't think I did.. Did you do that?

Comment: @toffee.beanns that was stupidly the last thing I did on my computer that had issues, after that I couldn't even run AHT

Comment: I was wondering if maybe that would affect it, but now that I think about it it doesn't make sense

Comment: @sam Is your mac running a dedicated graphics card? If it is, you can try to disable it to see if it helps.. (Given that mac mini is unable to run everything else - except boot screen on integrated graphics).. but as mentioned.. it will not run the same anymore.. because when the drivers are disabled, the mac no longer runs with graphics acceleration, which makes everything really choppy..  if your aim is to get the data out.. i would rather take the HDD/SSD out and retrieve it from another mac

Comment: It was a mid-2012 macbook pro, since I fix and upgrade them it's just been sitting open on my desk since it happened. Thank god someone gave me their kids old one (which was an identical computer) which I now use

Comment: Also, I have no idea if macbook pros run dedicated graphics cards

Comment: Lucky you! Actually, if it is a mbp, there is a possibility that you can use the integrated graphics card instead! From what I understand, you should be able to boot up once you disable the dedicated graphics card and run `gfxcardstatus` to do the gpu switching.

Comment: And also, those steps to disable the graphics card drivers are not permanent, so there's no risk trying out :)